# Complete akka-http response with an iterator

Tags: scala, serialization, akka-http

I have an iterator of mongodb query results and I want to stream those results to http response without loading the whole results set into memory.

Is it possible to complete akka http response with an iterator instead of a collection or future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an `Iterator` of data:

```
type Data = ???

val dataIterator : () => Iterator[Data] = ???
```

You will first need a function to convert `Data` to `ByteString` representation, and the `ContentType` ([e.g. json, binary, csv, xml, ...](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/model/ContentTypes$.html)) of the representation:

```
import akka.util.ByteString
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentType    

val dataToByteStr : Data => ByteString = ???

//see akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentTypes for possible values
val contentType : ContentType = ???
```

The Iterator and converter function can now be used to create an HttpResponse that will stream the results back to the http client without holding the entire set of Data in memory:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.{Chunked, ChunkStreamPart}
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ResponseEntity    
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse

val chunks : Source[ChunkStreamPart,_] = 
  Source.fromIterator(dataIterator)
        .map(dataToByteStr)
        .map(ChunkStreamPart.apply)

val entity : ResponseEntity = Chunked.fromData(contentType, chunks)

val httpResponse : HttpResponse = HttpResponse(entity=entity)
```

Note: Since a new Iterator is produced each time from `dataIterator` you don't have to create a new `httpResponse` for each incoming request; the same response can be used for all requests.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [Alpakka MongoDB connector](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/mongodb.html). It allows to create one Source from a Mongo collection like:

```
val source: Source[Document, NotUsed] = MongoSource(numbersColl.find())

val rows: Future[Seq[Document]] = source.runWith(Sink.seq)
```

Or you maybe want your own source implementation as a GraphStage for example.

Comment: I'm using salat and casbah.
I call collection.aggregate() and then I map{} the result several times